# Why does $dx$ disappear in the right-hand side?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am reading some text about even functions and found this snippet:

> Let $f(x)$ be an integrable even function. Then,
>
> $$\int_{-a}^0f(x)dx = \int_0^af(x)dx, \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$$
>
> and therefore,
>
> $$\int_{-a}^af(x)dx = 2\int_0^af(x), \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$$

Why does $dx$ disappear from $2\int_0^af(x)$? Is it just a notation convention?

Comment: It is a typo. $dx$ has to be there.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thanks. Can you post this as an answer? So I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathrm dx$ is supposed to be on the right hand side as well, and I guess that is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, there should be $dx$ term in integral. There is probably a typo.  For even function $f(x)$ i.e. $f(-x)=f(x)$, we have

$$\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=2\int_{0}^af(x)dx\quad \forall \ \ a\in \mathbb R$$